# Selenium IDE Firefox, find the right way button

Tags: class, selenium, firefox, button, ide

I've got a problem with **Selenium** to find the selector of a button. Here you can see his html code :

```
<div class="Right">
    <button class="ToolButton SELECT T1 " type="button"
            onclick="var button = $(this), grid = button.dgGetGrid(),title = 'Détails';; grid.dgOperationCompletedCallback('SELECT',3);"
            data-executionmode="popup" data-mode="2" data-key="SELECT"><span>Détails</span></button>
</div>
```

It seems that **Selenium** doesn't accept "button class" identifier.
Could you help me please?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: No, it works. What is the issue

Comment: I put : Button class=ToolButton SELECT F1 in "cible".
I got the following error message : [error] Unrecognised element-filter type: 'class'

Comment: use xpath //button[@class='ToolButton SELECT T1']

Comment: got : [error] Element xpath //button[@class='ToolButton SELECT T1'] not found. Even without "xpath".

Comment: Selenium does not care which element is being handled when you use class attribute. Can you locate that element using browser tools? Is it really  there?

Comment: Yes I'm using firebug to locate my button.
It gives me this 

<div class="Right">
<button class="ToolButton SELECT T1 " type="button" onclick="var button = $(this), grid = button.dgGetGrid(),title = 'Détails';; grid.dgOperationCompletedCallback('SELECT',3);" data-executionmode="popup" data-mode="2" data-key="SELECT">
<span>Détails</span>
</button>

Comment: There is a whitespace after T1 so that it should be taken into account when you set up xpath locator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
//button[@class='ToolButton SELECT T1 ']
```

Sine there is a whitespace after T1 as per your comment under your question.

Comment: @Mr_Absolut why did you mark another answer as a proper one then?

Answer (score 0):

Use XPath as below:-

```
//button[@class='ToolButton SELECT T1']
```

OR

```
//button[@class='ToolButton SELECT T1' and @type='button' and @data-key='SELECT']
```

Check.. are you T1 or F1?

Comment: Always the same error : //button[@class='ToolButton SELECT T1'] not found. For both.
I'm using "click" for commande.
it's T1 right.

Comment: do you have any frame as parent of this element.. if yes then you need to switch to frame first

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the space issue by using a CSS selector, which should be preferred over XPath in most situations anyway.

```
button.ToolButton.SELECT.T1
```

There are several issues with XPaths but, in this particular case, when you use an XPath you are doing an exact string match on the class value. If those classes change order or if a new class is added the locator will fail where the CSS selector will not. CSS selectors are also faster than XPath and better supported.